# how to merge in single list and do sum in python?

Tags: python, regex, list, iterator

**my code is:**

```
import sys
import re

from timeit import itertools

import operator

fileName = 'realfile.txt'

test = open(fileName)

for line in test:
total =0        
convert = re.findall(r'[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+', line)
result = map(int, convert)  
total = result
print total
```

**i got console output as :**

```
[]
[]
[]
[7152, 9977, 6801]
[]
[]
[4165]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[8572]
[9429, 4419, 3575]
[8032, 8040, 724]
[]
[5666, 7060, 807]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[1812]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[3512, 6831]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[472, 660, 5749]
[9413]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[4558]
[]
[]
[]
[1666, 7515, 1508]
[]
[2631, 3176]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[2439, 566, 1058]
[4406, 263, 3856]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[4192, 6521]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[7264, 4196]
[8948]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[4714, 6691, 6965]
[]
[]
[]
[7404, 1430]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[7259, 7475, 8892]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[7204]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[200, 5764]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[7160]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[7209, 2247, 6555]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[393]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[989, 8378]
[]
[]
[]
[4524, 1477]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[2689, 5418, 8761]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[1326]
[]
[]
[9050, 2979]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[1236]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[7009, 5660, 8064]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[9077, 4985, 5835]
[6548, 9909]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[4742, 7424, 7307]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[]
[6353]
[]
[]
[2123]
[]
[1311, 7273]
[]
[]
[]
[8933]
[]
[]
[]
[42]
[]
```

i tried using operator , reduce(lamda) function and so on but couldn't solve.
**All i want is to merge those different lists into single list and do sum. Any help would be appreciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a running total *before* you start the loop, then add each line's contents to that total:

```
total = 0
for line in test:
    convert = re.findall(r'[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+', line)
    result = map(int, convert)
    total += sum(result)

print total
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do

```
result = sum(map(int, convert))  
total = result+total
```

`total=0` should be out of `loop`.Take it before `for line in`

Answer (score 1):

```
result = []
for line in test:
    convert = re.findall(r'[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+', line)
    result = result + map(int, convert)
print result
print sum(result)
```

map return a list, keep adding this list in result list, At last you will have result list with all required integer. Then sum it.